# Is there a tangential surface integral?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have two different types of line integrals, the tangential line integral
$$\int_C  \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf r$$
and 
the normal line integral
$$\int_C  \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf n \,ds.$$

To give a motivation, these two different integrals are very helpful for understanding Divergence theorem and Stoke's theorem.

Let $\mathbf {F} = P \mathbf i + Q\mathbf j$. The Divergence Theorem says
$$\iint_D \text{div}(\mathbf F)\,dx\,dy = \int_C  \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf n \,ds.$$
This gives 
$$\iint_D (P_x + Q_y) \,dx\,dy=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot (-dy, dx) = \int_C P\,dy - Q\,dx.$$
Stoke's theorem is 
$$\iint_D \text{curl}(\mathbf F)\cdot \mathbf k \,dx\,dy = \int_C  \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf r$$
and this gives 
$$\iint_D (P_y - Q_x) \,dx\,dy=\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot (dx, dy) = \int_C P\,dx + Q\,dy.$$

Green's theorem can be derived from either of the two above theorems.

However, for all the surface integral, I have only seen the normal surface integral defined by 
$$\iint_D \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\, dS$$
is there a similar concept that is close to the tangential line integral $\int_C  \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Del}{\nabla}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$For vector fields $\Vec{F} = P\, \Vec{i} + Q\, \Vec{j}$ in the plane, there is a *complex structure*, defined by
$$
J(\Vec{F}) = -Q\, \Vec{i} + P\, \Vec{j}.
\tag{1}
$$

If $\Vec{n}$ is an outward-pointing unit normal field along the boundary of a plane region $\dd D$, then $J(\Vec{n}) = \Vec{t}$ is a unit tangent field oriented appropriately for Green's theorem.

If $\Vec{F}$ is a continuously-differentiable vector field in $D$, then
$$
\Del \times J(\Vec{F})
  = \frac{\dd P}{\dd x} + \frac{\dd Q}{\dd y}
  = \Del \cdot \Vec{F}.
\tag{2}
$$
Equation (2) and the fact that
$$
\Brak{\Vec{F}, \Vec{n}}
  = \Brak{J(\Vec{F}), J(\Vec{n})}
  = \Brak{J(\Vec{F}), \Vec{t}}
$$
account for the correspondence between Stokes's theorem and the divergence theorem in the plane.

---

Fatal snags occur for surfaces in $\Reals^{3}$:

1. There is no operator on a smooth surface in $\Reals^{3}$ mapping normal vectors to tangent vectors and *vice versa*. As both G Cab and A Ortiz note, a smooth surface in $\Reals^{3}$ has *dimension two* but *codimension one*. Any field $J$ of linear operators cannot be an isomorphism between the normal and tangent spaces.
2. There *might* exist (for a particular surface) a smooth field $J$ of operators sending a unit normal field to a "distinguished" unit tangent field, but no such operator field exists for a general surface: Applying such a $J$ to the outward unit normal field of a sphere, for example, would give a continuous, nowhere-vanishing tangent field on a sphere, which [does not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

---

In case it's of interest: The "correct" framework for [Stokes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem) is the [exterior calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). Loosely, there is "one theorem for each dimension". In the plane, Stokes's theorem and the divergence theorem are (from this perspective) *the same theorem* applied to *two different differential one-forms*: $P\, dx + Q\, dy$, and $-Q\, dx + P\, dy$.

The [index-raising and lowering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) operators associated to the Euclidean metric in $\Reals^{n}$ map vector fields to differential one-forms (associating, e.g., $P\, \Vec{i} + Q\, \Vec{j}$ and $P\, dx + Q\, dy$). This identification allows one to pass between vector and differential form versions of Stokes's theorem in the plane. A one-form, however, is a suitable integrand only on a curve.

To pass between vector and differential form versions of Stokes's theorem on a surface in $\Reals^{3}$, one identifies
$$
\Vec{i} \leftrightarrow dy \wedge dz,\qquad
\Vec{j} \leftrightarrow dz \wedge dx,\qquad
\Vec{k} \leftrightarrow dx \wedge dy.
$$
In fancy language, this is index-lowering followed by the [Hodge star-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to say firstly that I have not seen or thought of this concept before, and the definition I provide here does have its flaws. I am posting this not as a definitive answer, but as a foundation for someone who might like to develop this further.

Given a parametrized surface $T:(s,t)\mapsto(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))$, there is not a unique tangent vector $\mathbf v$ on the surface, unlike the uniqueness of a unit normal vector up to orientation.

Let's say the surface is defined by $T(s,t) = (x(s,t), y(s,t), z(s,t))$. Then,
$$
DT(s,t) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s,t) & \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(s,t) \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s,t) & \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(s,t) \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}(s,t) & \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}(s,t)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \vert&\vert \\
T_s(s,t) & T_t(s,t) \\
 \vert& \vert
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The vectors $T_s(s,t),T_t(s,t)$ form a basis $B$ for the tangent plane to $T$ at the point $(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t)).$ For a vector $\mathbf v_B$ in the span of $B$, we can express it in terms of the standard basis via $\mathbf v_\text{standard basis} = DT(s,t)\mathbf v_B.$

One way to define this integral, $I_{\mathbf v_B}$, is to pick a unit tangent vector $\mathbf v_B = (c_1,c_2)$ of two components $c_1$ and $c_2$ *that we are going to agree to fix* in order to specify a set combination of the vectors $T_s$ and $T_t$ (which do not change with respect to each other), and integrate $\mathbf F\cdot DT(s,t)\mathbf v_B$ with respect to $\mathrm d(s,t)$.

Define $I_{\mathbf v_B}$, the integral of a vector field $\mathbf F$ in the direction of $\mathbf v_B$, tangential to the surface $T$, parameters being taken from an open domain $U$ as

$$
I_{\mathbf v_B} = \iint_U\mathbf F(x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))\cdot D(s,t)\mathbf v_B\,\mathrm d(s,t).
$$
Then, $I_{\mathbf v_B}$ has the geometric interpretation of the net "flow" of $\mathbf F$ over the surface $T$ in a particular direction, tangent to the surface.

The main issue with this definition (assuming I haven't made silly algebra/calculus mistakes) is that instead of specifying a particular direction to integrate through in terms of the standard basis, this definition requires we choose some fixed combination of the surface tangent vectors $T_s$ and $T_t$, which makes it hard to see *which direction we are integrating along*, I think. I welcome others' thoughts and suggestions for how to improve what I have here.

Answer (score 2):

From a dimensional point of view, on a 3D surface, there is a 2D $dS$, and 
if $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS$ makes sense,  because $\mathbf{F}$ is 
$\text{something}/m^{\,2} $, then $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{t}\,dS$ makes sense as well.
Of course, on a surface you have two independent tangent vectors. 
A single specific one  will indicate a certain direction and the corresponding 
$\iint\limits_{\text{surface}} {\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{t}\,dS}$ the integral over a narrow band along a path onto the surface.

For example, for a body moving in a viscous fluid we can define $\mathbf{F}$ as the field of the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the body.
Then $\iint\limits_{\text{surface}} {\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS}$ will give the resultant of the normal pressure,
while $\iint\limits_{\text{surface}} {\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{t}_\mathbf{x} \,dS},\;\iint\limits_{\text{surface}} {\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{t}_\mathbf{y} \,dS}$ will give the resultant of the shear pressure, for example in the $x$ and $y$ direction.

Comment: I think your answer is to the point. But how could we have a specific expression for the tangential vector t? This would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really interesting. Indeed the definition of surface integral of a vector function is about the projection of a function on the normal vector, so it is impossible for tangential vector fields to be intergrated over a surface, for the integral would be always zero. I would like to extend this question a follows: I found this definition of $curl$ of a vector field: $$(\nabla \times \mathbf F)(p):=\lim_{V\to 0} \frac {1}{|V|} \oint_S \mathbf n \times \mathbf F dS, $$ where $p$ is a point inside a volume $V$ with boundary the surface $S$. The vector $\mathbf n \times \mathbf F$ is in fact tangential to the surface, and it sounds nice to integrate over the surface to find the given total rate. But I cannot understand the exact meaning of this "integral". Finally I would like to ask an equivalent to the original question: How could we present the circulation over $a$  $surface$ -and not over a curve?

Comment: This is effectively a new question that should be posted as such. It is not an answer to this OP.