# How could we define circulation over a surface or a tangential surface integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

The definition of surface integral of a vector function is about the projection of a function on the normal vector, so it is impossible for tangential vector fields to be intergrated over a surface, for the integral would be always zero. I would like to extend this thought as follows: I found this definition of $curl$ of a vector field: $$(\nabla \times \mathbf F)(p):=\lim_{V\to 0} \frac {1}{|V|} \oint_S \mathbf n \times \mathbf F dS, $$ where $p$ is a point inside a volume $V$ with boundary the surface $S$. The vector $\mathbf n \times \mathbf F$ is in fact tangential to the surface, and it sounds nice to integrate over the surface to find the given total rate. But I cannot understand the exact meaning of this "integral". I would like to ask: How could we present the circulation over $a$  $surface$ -and not over a curve?

Comment: are you asking for a rigorous definition of integration against $dS$, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I am asking about a strict definition of a "surface integral of tangential component of a vector field" and the geometric interpretation or intuition behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest an approach. Let $S$ a parametrized smooth surface of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf F:S\to \mathbb R^3$ a vector field. We also define the outer normal unit vector field of $S$ as $\mathbf n:S\to \mathbb R^3$ such that $\forall \mathbf p\in S : \mathbf n(\mathbf p)\bot \Pi_S(\mathbf p)$, where $\Pi_S(\mathbf p)$ is considered as the tangent plane of $S$ at $\mathbf p$. Let $\mathbf p\in S$. We clearly observe that vector $\mathbf F(\mathbf p)-(\mathbf F(\mathbf p)\cdot \mathbf n(\mathbf p))\mathbf n(\mathbf p)$ belongs to $\Pi_S(\mathbf p)$, thus it is tangential to $S$ at $\mathbf p$, and moreover it is the projection of our vector field on $\Pi_S$. Set $\mathbf t(\mathbf p)$ the normalized above tangent vector. By analogy with the common surface integral $\int_S \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S=\int_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf ndS$, we introduce $$\int_S \mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S_t=\int_S \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf t dS,$$
where the last expression equals to $$\int_D (\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf t)(\mathbf Σ(u,v))|(\mathbf Σ_u\times\mathbf Σ_v)(u,v)|dudv,$$
which is of course a double integral over the parametric region of $\mathbf Σ$.

In order to avoid the above expression of $\mathbf t$ and introduce a more compact one, we could define it as $$\mathbf t:=-\frac {\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)}{|\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)|},$$
thus $$\int_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf t dS=-\int_S \mathbf F \cdot \frac {\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)}{|\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)|} dS=\int_S (-\mathbf n \times \mathbf F)\cdot \frac {\mathbf F \times \mathbf  n}{|\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)|} dS=\int_S \frac {|\mathbf F \times \mathbf n|^2}{|\mathbf n \times(\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F)|} dS=\int_S \frac {|\mathbf F \times \mathbf n|^2}{|\mathbf  n\times \mathbf F|}dS=\int_S |\mathbf F \times \mathbf n|dS=\int_S |\mathbf F \times \mathbf d\mathbf S|,$$

where $d\mathbf S=\mathbf n dS$, as usual.

I think that this is a good attempt for "overall tangential contribution" of $\mathbf F$ on $S$, but I am not conclusively convinced about that.

Answer (score 0):

That "geometric" definition of curl can be found in [1] on p. 398 but they do not seem to prove it. It follows from the following

***Claim.*** *For any volume $V$ that is bounded by the closed surface $S$ and a differentiable vector field $\boldsymbol{F}$ we have
$$\tag{1}
\int_V\nabla\times \boldsymbol{F}\,dV=\oint_S\boldsymbol{n}\times \boldsymbol{F}\,dS
$$
where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the unit normal at the surface.*

Proof. Componentwise eq. (1) reads as
\begin{align}
\tag{2}\int_V\partial_2F_3-\partial_3F_2\,dV&=\oint_Sn_2F_3-n_3F_2\,dS\,,\\
\tag{3}\int_V\partial_3F_1-\partial_1F_3\,dV&=\oint_Sn_3F_1-n_1F_3\,dS\,,\\
\tag{4}\int_V\partial_1F_2-\partial_2F_1\,dV&=\oint_Sn_1F_2-n_2F_1\,dS\,.
\end{align}
Each of these equations follows directly from Gauss' divergence theorem applied to
the vector fields
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ F_3\\-F_2\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad
\begin{pmatrix} -F_3\\ 0\\F_1\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad
\begin{pmatrix} F_2\\ -F_1\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad
$$
respectively.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$

To answer your question about a surface integral of tangential component of a vector field:

- The RHS in (1) is a vector of ordinary surface integrals each of which contains the dot product of a vector field with the normal to the surface.
- Alternatively one can view the RHS of, say, (4) as the dot product $\boldsymbol{t}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}$ where
  $$\tag{5}
  \boldsymbol{t}=\begin{pmatrix}-n_2\\n_1\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
  This is a vector field tangential to the surface. See image below.
- For a unit sphere
  the unit normal is
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}
  $$
  and therefore the tangential field (5) is
  $$
  \boldsymbol{t}=\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
  Its curl is constant and points along the $z$-axis:
  $$
  \nabla\times 
  \boldsymbol{t}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
- It should be intuitively clear that the $z$-component of the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ is the surface integral (4) of the dot product $\boldsymbol{t}\cdot\boldsymbol{F}\,.$ The same reasoning applies to
  (2) and (3).

Image of the tangential field $\boldsymbol{t}\,:$
[image]

[1] K.F. Riley, M.P. Hobson, S.J. Bence, *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering.*

Comment: I will surely check the reference.  We  could comment many about your answer. I will focus on this:  The intuition behind surface integral of scalar fields as "mass density functions per unit area" is the calculation of overall surface' s "mass". The question is how the RHS vector as "a three-component mass" vector would give us the overall tangential vector field? Are we also  able to find a more suitable and immediate way to approach it?

Comment: The notion of "tangential" surface integral was discussed in the seven year old [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1924733/949989) that you already know. The Riley formula I proved above is by all means a bunch of three scalar surface integrals. It has nothing to do with surface area, nor with "mass". Nobody said that all surface integrals must have the same intuitive interpretation. Here we have one in front of us that perhaps needs more rigor and less intuition.

Comment: I think it is obvious that I used notions such "mass" and "area" metaphorically; there is no hint of necessity in my words. However any rigor math approach is not so loose in intuitive interpretations. Here the problem is a. that we are used to the definition of surface integral of a vector field as an integration of its normal component -my question lies in it- and b. it is not clear to me why this vector with components surface integrals of scalars answers my question.

Comment: You already said correctly that $\boldsymbol{n}\times\boldsymbol{F}$ is tangent to the surface. I do not know what else to say about the  exact meaning of the integral than what I wrote in the answer. Now I recommend to take a few explicit examples: $V$ the unit cube and $F=(y,0,0)$ or $(0,z,0)$ or $(0,0,x)\,.$

Comment: Please, read my answer below. I think that at least we get a better idea about the  notion of tangential. (Vector t is better than the cross product above)

Comment: I never had a problem with tangentials and prefer not to read that answer. If it clarifies anything to you why not.

Comment: No problem! -but no force made you concern yourself with this question; you chose!

Comment: I am not complaining about the question. It was interesting and I learned something.