# To evaluate $\int \int_{S} \hat{n}×(\bar{a} × \bar{r}) dS$

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

There's this surface integral question which I can't make sense of.

Given $\bar{a}$, a constant vector and $V$ is the volume enclosed by surface $S$, then $\int \int_{S} \hat{n}×(\bar{a} × \bar{r}) dS$ is equal to..

We usually integrate $\bar{F}\cdot n$ in surface integral which becomes a scalar function, but here integrand is vector.

Any help or hint. Thanks.

Comment: "but here integrand is vector" Integrate each component separately. Use the triple product expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Triple_product_expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to (1) in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732023/how-could-we-define-circulation-over-a-surface-or-a-tangential-surface-integral/4732131#4732131) the surface integral equals
$$
\int_V\nabla\times(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{r})\,dV\,.
$$
The proof is simple and essentially a componentwise application of Gauss' theorem.
Using
$$
\nabla\times(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{r})=2\,\mathbf{a}
$$
there is not much we have to do. The surface integral equals $2\,\mathbf{a}\,{\rm vol}(V)\,.$