# How to understand curl means rotation

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

Just by looking at the definition of curl:

$${\displaystyle \nabla \times \mathbf {F} =\left({\frac {\partial F_{z}}{\partial y}}-{\frac {\partial F_{y}}{\partial z}}\right){\boldsymbol {\hat {\imath }}}+\left({\frac {\partial F_{x}}{\partial z}}-{\frac {\partial F_{z}}{\partial x}}\right){\boldsymbol {\hat {\jmath }}}+\left({\frac {\partial F_{y}}{\partial x}}-{\frac {\partial F_{x}}{\partial y}}\right){\boldsymbol {\hat {k}}}}$$

how to understand this measures the magnitude of circulation?

use the X axis as example:

$$\left({\frac {\partial F_{z}}{\partial y}}-{\frac {\partial F_{y}}{\partial z}}\right){\boldsymbol {\hat {\imath }}}$$

It is the rate of change of z component of F with respect to change of y minus the rate of change of y component of F with respect to change of z. how is that related to rotation?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant thread about how to discover the classical Stokes’s theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4323512/40119 I compute the circulation around a tiny parallelogram and the curl formula pops out.

Comment: This may be of interest:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE

Comment: Look at the case $\mathbf{F}=-y\mathbf{e}_x+x\mathbf{e}_y=\rho\mathbf{e}_\theta$ where $(\rho,\theta,z)$ is the cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732023/how-could-we-define-circulation-over-a-surface-or-a-tangential-surface-integral/4732131#4732131).

Comment: I thought the answer that @Justauser posted then deleted had some useful intuition. Maybe they will undelete it.